# AWS - Is there a way to log all the entries of user access into the application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, watch

I am a newbie to AWS.

May I know if I can find/enable full logs of user activities on the application that is hosted in AWS. Can cloud watch do that?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  What is *"the application that is hosted in AWS?"*

Comment: May be its not clear for you.  "the application that is hosted in AWS?" =  A website site developed in PHP              I Know that we can store logs under var/logs using PHP functions. My question is, is there any service available on AWS that can record all the user activities happening in an application .